# How to find all files that don't contain a string?

Tags: batch-file, for-loop

I've found the following code on this site:

```
@echo off
setlocal
set "rootFolder=c:\yourRootPath"
set "fileMask=*.txt"
set "outFile=missing.txt"

>"%outFile%" (
  for /d %%D in ("%rootFolder%") for %%F in ("%%D\%fileMask%") do (
    findstr /nbr "$O..*\.MIN%%" "%%F" | findstr /bl "1:" >nul || echo %%F
  )
)
```

However, when I run the batch file, I receive the following error: "for was unexpected at this time."

My research says that this is normally caused by not using a double `%%`, but obviously this is not the case. 
I guess it is something simple, but I can't work it out, any tips please?

Comment: Your first `for` statement doesn't have an accompanying `do`. For a VBA analogy, that's like an `if` without a `then`.

Comment: How curious – [the original](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14386689/2564301) has this as well.

Answer (score 0):

This method should run much faster:

```
@echo off
setlocal

set "rootFolder=c:\yourRootPath"
set "fileMask=*.txt"
set "outFile=%~P0missing.txt"

cd "%rootFolder%"
findstr /S /M /B /R "$O..*\.MIN%%" "%fileMask%" > temp.tmp
( dir /S /A-D /B "%fileMask%" | findstr /V /G:temp.tmp ) > "%outFile%"
del temp.tmp
```

The `missing.txt` file is stored in the same folder of the Batch file, that must NOT be in the folder of the search files!